# Prove that $D$ is a simply connected domain

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Definition. A region $D$ is said to be simply connected if any simple closed curve which lies entirely in $D$ can be pulled to a single point in $D$ (a curve is called simple if it has no self intersections).

Let us consider the strip:

$$D=\{ s=α+iβ∈ℂ: a<α<b,\ β\in\Bbb R \}$$

where $a,b$ are real numbers.

Prove that $D$ is a simply connected domain.

Comment: Have you tried constructing a homotopy? I should also ask, what do closed simple curves contained in $D$ look like?

Comment: @JonathanY., dado: In fact I have no idea to start.

Comment: @StefanH. The imaginary part of $s$.

Comment: @StefanH. Any number.

Comment: Nice...I see you're trying to get that your harmonic functions in your other question are analytic. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use the fact that the $D$ is convex. Take a simple closed curve, and draw a "line" connecting it to a single point.

Comment: Right away we're going to run into difficulties, looking for one ;)